# How do I change file extension with javascript

Tags: javascript, programming-languages, methods

Does anyone know an easy way to change a file extension in Javascript?

For example, I have a variable with "first.docx" but I need to change it to "first.html".

Answer (score 99, accepted):

This will change the *string containing* the file name;

```
let file = "first.docx";

file = file.substr(0, file.lastIndexOf(".")) + ".htm";
```

For situations where there may not be an extension:

```
let pos = file.lastIndexOf(".");
file = file.substr(0, pos < 0 ? file.length : pos) + ".htm";
```

Comment: Note that there's an edge case if you use this on a filename that doesn't already have an extension.

Comment: how would i achieve setting the file format if i'm downloading from a website that doesn't provide a typical file?? it's just a url. i.e. **https://r5---sn-uxa0n-t8gs.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?ipbits=0&initcwndb…D134213BA9465CB74DFD36CDE47BF.102638C4A9F3ACA357F79EE747DD5F49F1E0F0DE**

Comment: This code is for getting an existing extension from a known file name, if you don't have a file name your problem is different.  Submit a new question perhaps.

Comment: This fails for paths like `foo.bar/qux`, i.e. no extension but dot in parent dir name. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57371333/3425536) for a solution that also handles these cases.

Answer (score 38):

I'd use this:

```
path.format({ ...path.parse('/path/to/file.txt'), base: '', ext: '.md' })
```

to change `"/path/to/file.txt"` to `"/path/to/file.md"`.

Comment: ^^ that should be marked as the right answer as it lets the framework worry about edge cases.

Comment: why did you set base to empty string? if my path to file starts with '../' setting base to empty string breaks

Comment: @Eric Kim It doesn't though

Comment: @EricKim
`base` is set to an empty string (`undefined` is also okay) because `path.format` ignores `pathObject.ext` if `pathObject.base` is set. You can see this [in the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#pathformatpathobject)

Answer (score 34):

In Node.js:

```js
path.join(path.dirname(file), path.basename(file, path.extname(file)) + '.md')
```

or more readably:

```js
// extension should include the dot, for example '.html'
function changeExtension(file, extension) {
  const basename = path.basename(file, path.extname(file))
  return path.join(path.dirname(file), basename + extension)
}
```

Unlike the accepted answer, this works for edge cases such as if the file doesn't have an extension and one of the parent directories has a dot in their name.

Answer (score 18):

```
file = file.replace(/\.[^.]+$/, '.html');
```

Comment: The problem is: I don't know which extention the input file has

Comment: What if the file's name were "file.name.docx" ?

Comment: @Juan - Your comment would be more appropriate on @Alex K's answer.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: why? can you point me to a link that says I should not comment on an answer saying that another is better? I'll stop doing so if this is a general rule here.

Comment: Regex for something this simple is the Golden Hammer AntiPattern (http://sourcemaking.com/antipatterns/golden-hammer)

Comment: @JuanMendes other than the unneeded escapes on the dots, `/.[^.]+$/` this is a fine solution to the question. Not sure why there is so much protest?

Answer (score 6):

This probably won't get many upvotes but I couldn't resist.

This code will deal with the edge case where a file might not have an extension already (in which case it will add it). It uses the ["tilde trick"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28757111/829771)

```
function changeExt (fileName, newExt) {
  var _tmp
  return fileName.substr(0, ~(_tmp = fileName.lastIndexOf('.')) ? _tmp : fileName.length) + '.' + newExt
}
```

EDITED: thanks @kylemit for a much better gist which uses the same logic, but in a much much neater way:

```
function changeExt(fileName, newExt) {
  var pos = fileName.includes(".") ? fileName.lastIndexOf(".") : fileName.length
  var fileRoot = fileName.substr(0, pos)
  var output = `${fileRoot}.${newExt}`
  return output
}

console.log(changeExt("img.jpeg", "jpg"))             // img.jpg
console.log(changeExt("img.name.jpeg", "jpg"))        // img.name.jpg
console.log(changeExt("host", "csv"))                 // host.csv
console.log(changeExt(".graphqlrc", "graphqlconfig")) // .graphqlconfig
```

Comment: Hey Merc, dredging up this answer from 3 years ago.  It's clever, but a doozy of a one-liner.  Might I humbly suggest replacing this [ES6 version in gist](https://gist.github.com/KyleMit/be4790e984410326ea6d9351fd13f1ee) which handles the same edge cases, but with a little more clarity

Comment: Nice one. I hate oneliners too :D

Answer (score 2):

`path.parse("first.docx").name + ".html"`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Comment: Careful: this only works if the path you have doesn't contain a directory. For example, if your input is `foo/first.docx`, this answer will drop the directory and result in `first.html`

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific method for setting a file extension in JavaScript or in Node.js so the solution boils down to modifying the string.

```js
let file = 'test.txt';

function changeFileExtension(str,ext){
  return str.split('.')[0] + `.${ext}`;
}

console.log(changeFileExtension(file,'html'));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var file = "first.docx";
file = file.split(".");
file = file[0]+".html";
```

Comment: This seems to be a rather complex way of solving the problem.

Comment: It's not complex, split is very easy to understand, it may do more work than you need though. However this solution doesn't account for periods in the file name

Comment: This fails if filename is `first.example.docx` etc.