# What does a tilde do when it precedes an expression?

Tags: javascript, syntax, bit-manipulation

```
var attr = ~'input,textarea'.indexOf( target.tagName.toLowerCase() )
           ? 'value'
           : 'innerHTML'
```

I saw it in an answer, and I've never seen it before.

What does it mean?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does !!~ (double not and tilde) preceding this array method call do?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9316612/1048572)

Answer (score 319, accepted):

`~` is a [bitwise operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) that flips all bits in its operand.

For example, if your number was `1`, its binary representation of the [IEEE 754 float](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) (how JavaScript treats numbers) would be...

```
0011 1111 1111 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

So `~` converts its operand to a 32 bit integer (bitwise operators in JavaScript do that)...

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001
```

<sup>If it were a negative number, it'd be stored in 2's complement: invert all bits and add 1.</sup>

...and then flips all its bits...

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110
```

> So what is the use of it, then? When might one ever use it?

It has a quite a few uses. If you're writing low level stuff, it's handy. If you profiled your application and found a bottleneck, it could be made more performant by using bitwise tricks (as one *possible* tool in a much bigger bag).

It's also a (generally) unclear *trick* to turn `indexOf()`'s *found* return value into *truthy* (while making *not found* as *falsy*) and people often use it for its side effect of truncating numbers to 32 bits (and dropping its decimal place by doubling it, effectively the same as `Math.floor()` for positive numbers).

I say *unclear* because it's not immediately obvious what it is being used for. Generally, you want your code to communicate clearly to other people reading it. While using `~` may *look cool*, it's generally too clever for its own good. :)

It's also less relevant now that JavaScript has [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) and [`String.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes). These return a boolean value. If your target platform(s) support it, you should prefer this for testing for the existence of a value in a string or array.

Comment: So what is the use of it, then? When might one ever use it?

Comment: Is nasty the right word? If it works I'd just call it an idiom of the language. There's many idioms. Once you learn them they are not unclear. List comprehensions are not clear in Python if you don't know them and can be accomplished with more verbose loops but you'd never ask a Python programmer not to use them. Similarly `value = value || default` in JavaScript is a common and valid idiom as long as you know when you can and can't use it.

Comment: @gman I guess it doesn't really matter if someone uses it or not. I think comparing list comprehensions (language feature) to this isn't really the same thing (*clever* way to avoid typing some extra characters). If you think *nasty* is too harsh a term, please feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: Maybe a more common example is `v = t ? a : b;`. I find that much clearer than `var v; if (t} { v = a; } else { v = b; }` usually broken across 5+ lines and also clearer than `var v = b; if (t) { v = a; }` which would usually be 4+ lines. But I know lots of people not familiar with the `? :` operators who would prefer the second or third way. I find the first is more readable. I agree with the general principle, make the code clear, don't use hacks. I guess I just see `~v.indexOf('...')` to be very clear once I've learned it.

Comment: When you're working in a large corporation with many developers you want code to be clearly written (ENGLISH) and well documented. The point of high level coding in a language with garbage collection is to avoid thinking about binary operations, and many front-end developers don't even have assembly language experience under their belts.

Comment: A helpful article explaining the `~` operator and some of it's common uses as described in this answer:  https://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/great-mystery-of-the-tilde/

Comment: Being that it's 5 years later: All major browsers, including Edge, except IE (any version) support `includes()`. Since W3 says more people use IE/Edge than opera and Safari combined, this is something to be wary of if you're developing with **IE** at all in mind. To make matters worse, browser detection in 2017 is still a muddy thing. Every detector I tried got one of Chrome/IE/Edge wrong, one identifying Edge as Chrome.

Comment: @RegularJoe You should almost never try to do browser detection, it makes many years that everybody understood that doing "feature" detection is way more relevant. Detecting the includes() method is very easy and polyfying it for IE is straightforward and even better, most JS/HTML5 API MDN documentation include a Polyfill section (ex: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Polyfill )

Comment: i wouldn't call `~` idiomatic. it's technically part of the language *spec*, but it's not so much part of the language *in general use*.

Comment: @gman Using `~(...).indexOf(...)` when you have `.includes(...)` is **never** idiomatic, the right words are _cryptic and nasty_.

Comment: @КонстантинВан, `includes` didn't exist when this answer and comments were written. I agree with you, now that it does exist it's the best option. 

Answer (score 138):

Using it before an `indexOf()` expression effectively gives you a truthy/falsy result instead of the numeric index that's directly returned.

If the return value is `-1`, then `~-1` is `0` because `-1` is a string of all  1 bits.  Any value greater than or equal to zero will give a non-zero result. Thus,

```
if (~someString.indexOf(something)) {
}
```

will cause the `if` code to run when "something" is in "someString".  If you try to use `.indexOf()` as a boolean directly, then that won't work because sometimes it returns zero (when "something" is at the beginning of the string).

Of course, this works too:

```
if (someString.indexOf(something) >= 0) {
}
```

and it's considerably less mysterious.

Sometimes you'll also see this:

```
var i = ~~something;
```

Using the `~` operator twice like that is a quick way to convert a string to a 32-bit integer. The first `~` does the conversion, and the second `~` flips the bits back.  Of course if the operator is applied to something that's cannot be converted to a number, you get `NaN` as a result. (*edit* — actually it's the second `~` that is applied first, but you get the idea.)

Comment: For those who don't want to negate bit by bit, `~` when performed on integers is equal to `-(x + 1)`.

Comment: Seems like, well, you know, _**NEGATIVE**_ numeric values should return negative boolean ones as well in the first place.  But just another one of JS' fails, I guess?

Comment: @adlwalrus well the tradition of `0` being `false` and non-zero being `true` dates way back, at least to C in the '70s and probably lots of other then-contemporary systems programming languages. It probably stems from the way the hardware works; lots of CPUs set a zero bit after an operation, and have a corresponding branch instruction to test it.

Comment: A quicker way to convert it to a 32 bit int would be `| 0`, in which case its only one operation.

Comment: @alex indeed, though we can't necessarily trust the runtime not to interpret a simple application of `~~` exactly the same way.

Comment: if you dont want to use the (~), then could use (1+) as well: if ( 1 + someString.indexOf(something))

Comment: This is one of the things you should know but don't do. Just use `x.indexOf(y) !== -1` for gods sake.

Comment: @Semra, I do agree with you but the code. **`x.includes(y)`** should be preferred at any cases.

Answer (score 40):

The `~` is [Bitwise NOT Operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-bitwise-not-operator), `~x` is roughly the same as `-(x+1)`. It is easier to understand, sort of. So:

```
~2;    // -(2+1) ==> -3
```

Consider `-(x+1)`. `-1` can perform that operation to produce a `0`.

In other words, `~` used with a range of number values will produce a falsy (coerce to `false` from `0`) value only for the `-1` input value, otherwise, any other truthy value.

As we know, `-1` is commonly called a *sentinel value*. It is used for many functions that return `>= 0` values for *success* and `-1` for *failure* in C language. Which the same rule of return value of [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) in JavaScript.

It is common to check of presence/absence of a substring in another string in this way

```
var a = "Hello Baby";

if (a.indexOf("Ba") >= 0) {
    // found it
}
if (a.indexOf("Ba") != -1) { 
    // found it
}

if (a.indexOf("aB") < 0) { 
    // not found
}
if (a.indexOf( "aB" ) == -1) { 
    // not found
}
```

However, it would be more easily to do it through `~` as below

```
var a = "Hello Baby";

~a.indexOf("Ba");         // -7   -> truthy
if (~a.indexOf("Ba")) {   // true
    // found it
}

~a.indexOf("aB");         // 0    -> falsy
!~a.indexOf("aB");        // true
if (!~a.indexOf( "aB" )) {  // true
    // not found
}
```

[You Don't Know JS: Types & Grammar by Kyle Simpson](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/you-dont-know/9781491905159/ch04.html)

Comment: It's _definitely_ easier to understand at face value, even if a person doesn't understand the background that makes it work. I'd take a second look at `-(x+1)` if I saw it in an if statement. The tilde tells me exactly what it's doing to compensate for Javascript's 0-based nature. _Also, the less parentheses the better for reading_

Comment: In your initial check code block you could type less by using `if (a.indexOf("Ba") > -1) {// found} //true` which, although a bit lengthier than the tilde examples, is considerably less than the two examples you gave and for new programmers `var opinion = !~-1 ? 'more' : 'less'` understandable.

Answer (score 29):

`~indexOf(item)` comes up quite often, and the answers here are great, but maybe some people just need to know how to use it and "skip" the theory:

```
   if (~list.indexOf(item)) {
     // item in list
   } else {
     // item *not* in list
   }
```

Comment: I concur. Airbnb JavaScript Style Guide disallows `++` and `--` because they "encourage excessive trickiness" and yet somehow `~` survived (lurking in the shadows) https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/540

Comment: @Shanimal The alternative is `list.indexOf(item) >= 0` or `... > -1` since javascript is zero-based and didn't choose to address this from the outset. Further, just opinion (same as Airbnb's), anyone who is doing anything meaningful in javascript knows `++`, and while `--` is less common, the meaning can be inferred.

Comment: @RegularJoe I agree with most of that. I personally haven't needed `++` and `--` in a while because of primitive methods like `map`, `forEach` etc. My point is more about why they didn't also consider `~` excessively tricky when whatever standard used includes increment and decrement operators. To forbid something so CIS101 doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 16):

For those considering using the tilde trick to create a *truthy* value from an `indexOf` result, it is more explicit and has less magic to instead use the [`includes` method on `String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).

```
'hello world'.includes('hello') //=> true
'hello world'.includes('kittens') //=> false
```

Note that this is a new standard method as of ES 2015 so it won't work on older browsers. In cases where that matters, consider using the [String.prototype.includes polyfill](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/String.prototype.includes).

This feature is also available for arrays using the [same syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries'].includes('apples') //=> true
['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries'].includes('unicorns') //=> false
```

Here is the [Array.prototype.includes polyfill](https://github.com/ljharb/array-includes) if you need older browser support.

Comment: Avoid using includes(). It is not supported in any version of IE (not just older browsers) at the time of writing:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: Or just use a compiler, so you can write clearer code, instead of writing the language according to the worst common denominator JS interpreter out there...

Comment: @Ben is right, it doesn't work in Netscape 4.72 either.

Comment: @Onshop, I believe **what should be really avoided is** not the standard Javascript, but **IE, which doesn't support it.**