# Form Validation: If data in form contains "VP-", error out

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I'm trying to do code that errors out a form validate if the form contains "VP-".

My code is:

```
// quick order form validation
function validateQuickOrder(form) {        
  if ((form.ProductNumber.value == "")|| (form.ProductNumber.value == "VP")){
        alert("Please enter an item number.");
        form.ProductNumber.focus();
        return false;
 }
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Whats not working? Whats expected and what are you getting?

Comment: if it IS or if it contains? because you're only checking if it is literally "VP" there.

Comment: Expecting to receive the alert, but not receiving anything; form still submitting with no problem using my code above. I want it to encounter a problem, and display alert if I enter a product number that contains "VP"

Comment: `form.ProductNumber.value.indexOf('VP') > -1`

Comment: @Aidanc - If it contains anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`==` does a full string comparison. You'll want to use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to check if it *contains* that string:

```
if ( ~form.ProductNumber.value.indexOf('VP') ) {
    // ProductNumber.value has "VP" somewhere in the string
}
```

The tilde is [a neat trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299665/what-does-a-tilde-do-when-it-precedes-an-expression#answer-12299678), but you can be more verbose if you want:

```
if ( form.ProductNumber.value.indexOf('VP') != -1 ) {
    // ProductNumber.value has "VP" somewhere in the string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide an alternative to the other answer, regex can be used as well:

```
if ( /VP/.test( form.ProductNumber.value ) ) {
  // value contains "VP"
}
```