# What exactly does ~ do?

Tags: javascript, operators

I see sometimes the symbol `~` in code. I tried it with `~1`, and it shows `0`. 
And thus, I can see some code using this trick:

```
if ( !~text.indexOf('a') ){ }
```

To check for truthy value. Is it kind of bit shifting?

Comment: `~1` should return `-2`. **`~-1`** returns `0`.

Comment: Check out the marked answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299665/what-does-a-tilde-do-when-it-precedes-an-expression

Answer (score 3):

It's the [bitwise NOT operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators). It will convert the operand to an 32-bit integer, then yields [one's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) (inverts every bit) of that integer.

Finally, `!` will return `true` if and only only if the result of that operation is `0`.

Some examples might help:

```
  x |   x (bin) | ~x (bin)  |  ~x |   !~x
 -3 | 1111…1101 | 0000…0010 |   2 | false
 -2 | 1111…1110 | 0000…0001 |   1 | false
 -1 | 1111…1111 | 0000…0000 |   0 |  true
  0 | 0000…0000 | 1111…1111 |  -1 | false
  1 | 0000…0001 | 1111…1110 |  -2 | false
```

In other words,

```
if ( !~text.indexOf('a') ) { }
```

is equivalent to:

```
if ( text.indexOf('a') == -1 ) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

`~` is the [bitwise negation operator<sup>[MDN]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators). It converts its operand to a 32-bit integer and swaps all the `1`s to `0`s and all the `0`s to `1`s.

For example:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 = 0
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 = ~0 = -1
```

Instead of doing `text.indexOf(str) !== -1)` you can use the tricky  `!~text.indexOf(str)`, because `~1 === 0` and `!0 === true`.

Answer (score 0):

`~` is the unary negation operator. Basically converts the operand to a 32-bit integer and then flips every bit of the integer.

```
~12 =
~(00000000 00000000 00000000 00001100) =
 (11111111 11111111 11111111 11110011) =
-13
```