# Meaning of ~ in javascript function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm reading this javascript function:

```
if (~['bacon', 'burger'].indexOf(type)) {
    this.res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    this.res.end('Serving ' + type + ' sandwich!\n');
  }
```

But I'm not sure what means `~`  some one know when I use it or what meaning?

Comment: [JS bit-wise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

Comment: Bitwise NOT ~ a Inverts the bits of its operand.

Comment: Bitwise NOT operator -> [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Bitwise_operators)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does a tilde do when it precedes an expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299665/what-does-a-tilde-do-when-it-precedes-an-expression)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`~` is the bitwise NOT operator. It toggles every bit of a number.

- `0` becomes `-1`.
- `-1` becomes `0`.
- No other numbers become zero.

That means that

```
if (~['bacon', 'burger'].indexOf(type)) {
```

is a confusing way of writing

```
if (['bacon', 'burger'].indexOf(type) == -1) {
```

`indexOf` returns `-1` when it doesn't find the string.

Answer (score 3):

```
~ is a Bitwise NOT operator...
```

[Read more](http://www.javascriptturnsmeon.com/the-tilde-operator-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 2):

In this instance, the `~` allows that code to turn the return value of `.indexOf()` — which is a number indicating the position of the searched-for value in the array — into a boolean. In other words, it takes the "where is the value" result and turns it into a "is the value in the list" result.

How?  Well, `.indexOf()` returns `-1` when the value is not found, and a number greater than or equal to zero if it is. The `~` operator converts its numeric argument to a 32-bit integer and then inverts every bit. That process happens to turn `-1` to `0`, and any positive integer to some negative non-zero value, and `0` to `-1`.  When such results are subsequently examined as *boolean* values, the original `-1` will be `false` (because `0` is "falsy") while the integers greater than or equal to zero will be `true` (because they're all converted to some non-zero value).

Answer (score -1):

Bitwise NOT (~ a) Inverts the bits of its operand.

EXAMPLE

- 9 (base 10) = 00000000000000000000000000001001 (base 2)

  ```
         --------------------------------
  ```
- ~9 (base 10) = 11111111111111111111111111110110 (base 2) = -10 (base
  10)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Comment: Don't use someone's comment on the question as an answer. And don't use examples from **[other sites](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)** without giving credit

Comment: Please don't down-vote my answer for no reason at all in the future

Comment: At the time of my comment / vote, you only had some sample code copied from the dev.mozilla site in your answer.
Even now, all you have is that example and a link, without an explanation. _"Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect."_ **[Help center link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)**