# javascript: test if this.name == array element

Tags: javascript

I'm super new to javascript and learning.

I have this piece of code and it is running and getting the job done.

```
(this.name == ('nodepy') || this.name == ("nonlinear-waves-course") || this.name == ("SSP_Tools"))
```

but now I want to define an array or list of strings

```
var listOfRepos = ["nodepy", "nonlinear-waves-course", "SSP_Tools"];
```

How do I go about checking if "this.name" is in "listOfRepos"?

In python, I can just write something like this:

```
this.name in listOfRepos
```

Again, I'm new to javascript. Very little experience. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```
if (~listOfRepos.indexOf(this.name)){
    alert('true');
}
```

Explanation:

`indexOf()` returns the value's index in your array if it is in the array, if it's not it will return -1. I'm using the `bitwise not` operator `~`

> Bitwise NOT   inverts the bits of its operand.

Above could also be written as

```
if (listOfRepos.indexOf(this.name) > -1) {}
```

Comment: Bad idea to promote the use of the confusing `~` operator.

Comment: @torazaburo Have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_NOT), maybe that makes it clearer for you

Comment: I know exactly what it does. The problem is that 80% of JS programmers looking at the code will not. That's why it's generally discouraged. As this accepted answer with 37 upvotes says, *It's also a (generally) unclear trick*. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299665/what-does-a-tilde-do-when-it-precedes-an-expression