# Why "~undefined" is -1 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, undefined

According to this [post](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), run the following codes

```
> ~function () { console.log('foo');}()
  foo
  -1
```

As we all know, the return value of the above anonymous function is `undefined`. **Why `~undefined` is `-1`**? I couldn't find any similar question.

Comment: For anyone (like me), wondering what the tilde (`~`) does in JavaScript, [here is the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299665/what-does-a-tilde-do-when-it-precedes-an-expression).

Comment: Cause JavaScript, that's why!

Comment: @JoseFaeti or because someone cannot learn it properly, that's why!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[`~` is bitwise NOT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_NOT). It uses [`ToInt32`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-toint32) to convert the argument to a number. `ToInt32` is defined as:

> 1. Let number be ToNumber(argument).
> 2. ReturnIfAbrupt(number).
> 3. If number is NaN, +0, −0, +∞, or −∞, return +0.
>      ...

In turn, [`ToNumber(undefined)`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-tonumber) returns `NaN`, so according to step 3, `ToInt32` returns `0`.

And `~0` is `-1`.

Comment: Could you please points to where the standard says that *"operators are converted to signed 32-bit integers in two's complement format"* link to `ToInt32` (I am not questioning your answer, I am just curious)?

Comment: @Holt: I did link to the definition of `ToInt32`. Did you want a link to the spec of the NOT operator?

Comment: Yes, I found it [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-bitwise-not-operator) - The standard is far more explicit that the doc on developer.mozilla.org, I think it could be a good idea to add a link (or even quote) the standard for the `NOT` operator in your post.

Comment: all bitwise operators in javascript are done using (mainly) signed 32bit integers - I say mainly, because RHS of <<, >> and both LHS and RHS of >>> are unsigned 32bit

Comment: @JaromandaX I was asking because (for me) the quote from `developer.mozilla.org` is a bit equivocal, but the standard clearly points to `ToInt32`.

Answer (score 7):

every thing that cannot be represented in bits in JS for example "undefined, NaN" is treated a `0` or `0000000000000b` for the `~` operator since it converts the operand into an signed integer **see @felixkling answer** for more details on this and since the operation `~` is BITwise not or 1s complement which flips the bits so the statement results in `111111111111b` as a sequence of `1` and when dealing in numbers on binary level the MSB(most significant bit) is treated as a `sign` so when converting all the `0s` to `1s` it results in decimal value of `-1` try `~0` for instance. and use this code to get the binary representation of a number `(-3 >>> 0).toString(2))`

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the bit representation of `undefined` is all `0`s. This can be seen if by the following: `undefined | 0` which evaluates to `0`. Because of this we know that `undefined`'s bit representation is all zeros.

If we now filp all bits (wich is exactly what `~` does) we get all `1`s which is the representation of `-1`.

All this works because of javascript's type cohersion