# How ~(tilde)Infinity becomes -1

Tags: javascript

~Infinity my question is how it evaluate to -1.

> ~Infinity= -1

```js
console.log(~Infinity);
```

because

> Infinity+Infinity=Infinity

```js
console.log(Infinity+Infinity)
```

or

> Infinity-Infinity = NaN

```js
console.log(Infinity-Infinity)
```

How `~Infinity` output is coming to `-1`;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299665/what-does-a-tilde-do-when-it-precedes-an-expression

Comment: Bitwise operators truncate the operands to 32bit integers. And it so happens that truncating the value `Infinity` results in `0` (`Infinity | 0`). `~0` is `-1`.

Comment: @j08691 Interesting, but neither the question nor the answers seem to address OP's issue there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In IEEE 754 floating point, the `Infinity` constant is represented by a value with all the fraction bits set to 0.  When that's coerced to a 32-bit integer value in calculating the bitwise complement (the `~` unary operator), you get just zero, so the complement is all 1 bits, or -1.

Positive infinity is:

```
01111111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

(give or take a zero). The sign bit is 0, the exponent is all 1 bits, and the mantissa is all zeros.

Comment: It'd be cool to see the binary representation to get a clear idea of what's happening.