# In JavaScript, why does ~~Infinity evaluate to 0?

Tags: javascript

Can anybody explain:

- why double bitwise NOT for Infinity `returns 0`?

  ```
  ~~Infinity //return 0
  ```
- what happens under the hood?
- what is the binary representation of Infinity in javascript?

Comment: Not sure why the double is relevant. `~Infinity` is `-1`.

Comment: "What is the binary representation of Infinity in javascript?" JS uses the IEEE 754 standard for floating point numbers, so it would be (for pos inifinity) 0 sign, all 1s for an exponent and the mantissa would be 0 (js numbers are 64b, but a 32b ieee754 inf would look like 0 1111 1111 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 000)

Comment: You'll find some information here -> [Double bitwise NOT (~~)](https://j11y.io/cool-stuff/double-bitwise-not)

Comment: Update on my previous comment, according to [ES5 Section 4.3.22](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.22) Infinity isn't explicitly stated that it uses the IEEE754 standard (like NaN does), but according to [11.4.8](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.8) `ToInt32` is used in `~` which is described in [9.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.5) that NaN, +0, -0, +inf or -inf are converted to `+0`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How ~(tilde)Infinity becomes -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37882479/how-tildeinfinity-becomes-1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are not operating on the underlying bit pattern of a number in JavaScript.

You cannot do the equivalent of the following C code in JavaScript:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    double x = HUGE_VAL;
    uint64_t y = *((uint64_t *) &x);
    printf("%016" PRIx64 "\n", y);
    printf("%016" PRIx64 "\n", ~y);
    printf("%016" PRIx64 "\n", ~~y);
    return 0;
}
```

This prints:

```
7ff0000000000000
800fffffffffffff
7ff0000000000000
```

As [MDN notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Bitwise_operators):

> A bitwise operator treats their[sic] operands as a set of **32 bits** (zeros and ones), rather than as decimal, hexadecimal, or octal numbers. ... Bitwise operators perform their operations on such binary representations, but they return standard JavaScript numerical values.
>
> ... values with the most significant (left-most) bit set to 1 represent negative numbers (two's-complement representation).

According to [11.4.8 in ES5](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.8), we have:

> 11.4.8 Bitwise NOT Operator ( ~ )
>
> The production `UnaryExpression : ~ UnaryExpression` is evaluated as follows:
>
> - Let `expr` be the result of evaluating `UnaryExpression`.
> - Let `oldValue` be `ToInt32(GetValue(expr))`.
> - Return the result of applying bitwise complement to oldValue. The result is a signed 32-bit integer.

[`ToInt32(Infinity)` is `+0`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.5). The first `~` makes it `0xffffffff`. The second `~` flips all bits to zero.

That is, it does the equivalent of the following C code:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    double x = HUGE_VAL;
    uint32_t y = x;
    printf("%08X\n", y);
    printf("%08X\n", ~y);
    printf("%08X\n", ~~y);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
00000000
FFFFFFFF
00000000
```