# Does indexOf != -1 return a Boolean?

Tags: javascript

I have just started learning Javascript and I have a specific question about a specific piece of code below. It is part of the lycanthrope's log in chapter 4 of Eloquent Javascript. Because of the specificity of my question I haven't included all the other code associated with this problem for I believe it isn't necessary to answer my question.

Please do let me know if this is considered 'bad practice' and I will make sure to ammend this and/or future posts to show more background.

In the code below the second line shows a return. So far I have learned that indexOf returns a positive number or zero if and only if it finds an occurence of whatever is passed in it. If no occurence is found it returns -1.

In this case it is followed by != -1, which I understand to mean "not equal to minus 1". That is clear to me.

What I do not completely understand is what the actual return in line 2 ends up being. Does it return a Boolean value of either true or false? Or does it return he actual index where the 'event' is found?

Further on, in the first if-statement, we see the hasEvent variable again. I read this statement as "If hasEvent(event, entry) is true then add 1 to the index.

Am I 'reading' this right and is the return in the second line indeed a Boolean?

```
function hasEvent (event, entry) {
  return entry.events.indexOf(event) != -1;
}

function tableFor (event, journal) {
 var table = [0, 0, 0, 0];
 for (var i=0; i < journal.length; i++) {
  var entry = journal[i] , index = 0;
  if (hasEvent(event, entry)) index += 1;
  if (entry.squirrel) index += 2;
  table [index] += 1;
}
 return table;
}
```

Thank you for your help and please tell me if I should have stated this question differently! I am trying to make sure I understand things before I move on!

Comment: It returns the result of the comparison, which is a Boolean.

Comment: [`typeof(indexOf() != -1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep. Using `===`, `==`, `!`, `!==`, `!=`, `>`, `>=`, `<` or `<=` results in a boolean expression, which would return a boolean from `hasEvent`.

Answer (score 8):

The `!=` operator *always* has a boolean result.

A `return` statement followed by an expression returns the value of the expression, so the returned value of that function will be either `true` or `false`.

Comment: And better to use `!==` and `===`.

Comment: @Tushar in this case it makes no difference, because `.indexOf()` will always return a number.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. So then logically the first if statement indeed causes 1 to be added when the hasEvent value comes back as true?

Comment: Right. In the expression context where the function is *called*, the value will be whatever was returned. That'll be either `true` or `false`. If it's `true`, then the statement body of the `if` will execute.

Answer (score 1):

[Comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison_operators) all evaluate to a boolean value.

More to the point, what this code is specifically doing is abstracting a comparison behind a function name.  Any operation or set of operations which results in a value can be placed in a function which returns that value.  Doing so is a common refactoring to make code more readable and understandable, as the name of the function can impart intuitive meaning on the operation being performed.

So instead of something like this:

```
if (a == b) {

}
```

you can have this:

```
if (someCondition(a, b)) {

}
```

So you can give a meaningful *name* to the operation (more meaningful than `someCondition` of course).  As long as that function returns the same value as the code it replaces, logically there is no difference.

Answer (score 1):

#### Explanation

By default, the `indexOf` function returns the index location of the substring.

A bitwise shortcut can be used with `indexOf` as well as other functions:

- `~` (bitwise not operator):

  - This works similar to `~x => -(x+1)`

Simply checking against this value (for example using an if statement) yields true for non-zero values and false for zero.

If you need the actual boolean value instead, you can use the following: `!!~`. Here, the double exclamation `!!` is non-inverted boolean representation. Combining both essentially flips the result of `indexOf`, then converts it to boolean representation.

A better explanation of `~` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299665/what-does-a-tilde-do-when-it-precedes-an-expression). A better explanation of `!!` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)

#### Example

```js
let s = 'abc'

/*
console.log(~s.indexOf('a'))  // -1
console.log(~s.indexOf('b'))  // -2
console.log(~s.indexOf('d'))  //  0

console.log(!~s.indexOf('a')) // false
console.log(!~s.indexOf('b')) // false
console.log(!~s.indexOf('d')) // true

console.log(!!s.indexOf('a')) // false
console.log(!!s.indexOf('b')) // true
console.log(!!s.indexOf('d')) // true

console.log(~~s.indexOf('a')) // 0
console.log(~~s.indexOf('b')) // 1
console.log(~~s.indexOf('d')) // -1
*/

// This one works
console.log(!!~s.indexOf('a'))  // true: 0 => -1 => false => true
console.log(!!~s.indexOf('b'))  // true: 1 => -2 => false => true
console.log(!!~s.indexOf('d'))  // false: -1 => 0 => true => false
```