# What does -~ do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, operators, code-snippets

I am looking at someone else's code and I am trying to figure out what they are doing. The snippet in question looks like the following:

```
for(j in a)     
  for(i in a)
    y=a[i]+-~j,b=a[j]
```

I understand the `y=a[i]` part, but what does `+-~j` do?

Comment: Great example of how not to write code! Ever!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a tilde do when it precedes an expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299665/what-does-a-tilde-do-when-it-precedes-an-expression)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is (kind of?) clever use of the tilde (`~`) operator, but it just leads to confusion. The `~` (effectively) adds one to the number and flips the sign.

`~0 === -1`

`~1 === -2`

`~-1 === 0`

etc.

The `-` flips the sign back to what it originally was.

So the end result of `-~j` is `j + 1`

This then gets added to `a[i]` and assigned to `y`

> Moral of the story: don't ever write code like this.

**Note:** There are legitimate use-cases for the `~` operator, most notably in the `.indexOf()` function. If you want to check if something was found in an array/string, rather than saying:

`if (arr.indexOf("foo") > -1) {...}`, you can say

`if (~arr.indexOf("foo")){...}`. This is because if the value is not found, `indexOf()` will return -1, which, when passed through the tilde operator, will return 0, which coerces to false. All other values return 0 through n, which return -(1 through n+1) when passed through the tilde operator, which coerce to true.