# Why ~-(2 + "2") is 21?

Tags: javascript, operators

I saw this question in a test, but I don't understand how operators work on the statement.

```js
let a = ~-(2 + "2");
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Which part don't you understand? Break it down: `2 + "2"` -> `"22"`; then `-"22"` -> `-22`; then `~-22` -> `21`. Does [this existing Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12299665/3001761) answer your question? If not, could you [edit] to be more specific about what it is?

Comment: Did you try doing this a step at a time in the javascript console of your browser? Try `2 + "2"` first, and so on...

Comment: simple answer, because type coercion, maths and bitwise operations - all these are documented - try mdn documentation for up to date documentation

Comment: Check this out `https://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/great-mystery-of-the-tilde/`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
~-(2 + "2")
```

- 0: `2 + "2"` (Concatenation) = `"22"`
- 1: `-"22"` (Coercion) = `-22`
- 2: `~-22` (Bitwise NOT) = -(-22 + 1) = 21

> Bitwise NOTing any number x yields -(x + 1). For example, ~-5 yields 4.

Comment: According to your response ~-0xffffffff = -(-4294967295 + 1) = 4294967294. Sorry the result is -2

Comment: @tdjprog So is it correct to say that all numbers under `2^32` will behave as described by this answer, and that those above that threshold will overflow in some way and behave differently?

Answer (score 2):

- Step 1: `(2+"2")` results in the string `"22"`
- Step 2: `-("22")` is the same as (-1)*("22"), and results in the number `-22`
- Step 3: Bitwise not (`~`), which results in `21`

To understand that last step, you need to know that JavaScript stores numbers as 64-bit floating point numbers, but all bitwise operations are performed on 32-bit signed integers using 2's compliment.

So:

- -22 representation is the 2's compliment of +22
- +22 in binary = `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0110`
- 2's compliment of (22) = (-22) = `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110 1001`
- - 1 = `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110 1010`
- `~-22` = bitwise not of -22 = `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0101`
- `10101` in binary = `21` in decimal