# What does '!!~' do in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

I saw following piece of code on github.

```
/**
 * Filters an array of objects with multiple criteria.
 *
 * @param  {Array}  array: the array to filter
 * @param  {Object} filters: an object with the filter criteria as the property names
 * @return {Array}
 */
function multiFilter(array, filters) {
  const filterKeys = Object.keys(filters);
  // filters all elements passing the criteria
  return array.filter((item) => {
    // dynamically validate all filter criteria
    return filterKeys.every(key => !!~filters[key].indexOf(item[key]));
  });
}
```

I don't understand, what does `!!~` do here?

**PS:** I know C and C++ languages and but I'm newbie with Javascript. I know about that operators but I don't understand, Why does use double negation(`!!`) with bitwise not(`~`) operator?

Comment: Take the negation of a negation, which is a way to cast it to a Boolean. For some bizarre reason they've then done a bitwise negation on that.

Comment: It's just another way to "cast" to a boolean, not sure for what kind of reason there is the extra bitwise negation which is, to me, entirely unnecessary, unless it's somehow transforming the indexof.

Comment: I would like to know is `!!~` faster than `!= -1`?

Comment: @TerryWei: I rmb saw someone made the comparison and bitwise is slightly faster. But the amount is negligible

Comment: use `includes()` which  returns a boolean ( true or false ). if you want to know if an element is inside an array/string. No need to use this `~` as it's very hard to read and understand if anyone will ever look over your code. Just because you can use something doesn't mean you should :)

Comment: `!!` is superfluous, because filter expect a boolean value which is converted to, if not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`indexOf` will return the index `0-x` if the element is found, `-1` otherwise.

`~` will change all the bits in the number, turning `-1` to `0` (the binary represantation of `-1` is `1111 1111 ...`).

`0` is a falsy value, all other numbers are truthy.

`!!` will convert a falsy value to `false` and a truthy value to `true`. It wouldn't be needed here, because `every` doesn't care whether it recieves a truthy value or true.

As others have mentioned, nowadays you could use `includes`. However, `includes` is newer to the JavaScript ecosystem than `indexOf`, so this solution would work in IE, the solution with `include` would not. You could still use `includes` in IE either by providing a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) or by transpiling your code.

Answer (score 3):

The [tilde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299665/what-does-a-tilde-do-when-it-precedes-an-expression) turns the resulting `indexOf` expression truthy if the item is found, and falsey if the item is not found. The `!!` then converts the result to a boolean from a number. (which is not useful at all, since `every` only cares about whether the result is truthy or falsey)

It's terribly unclear. It would be much better to use this instead:

```
return array.filter((item) => {
  // dynamically validate all filter criteria
  return filterKeys.every(key => filters[key].includes(item[key]));
});
```

Comment: Oh. So the tilde is actually clever in this case. Nice catch.

Comment: `Clever` at the expense of others being able to understand your code easily is actually not clever at all IMO.

Comment: my clever was refered to you guessing that the tilde was there for that reason specifically, not really to the code readability :P

Answer (score 1):

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var a = ~fruits.indexOf("Banana");
var b = !a;
var c = !!a;
console.log('a:',a);
console.log('b:',b);
console.log('c:',c);
```

It can be break into steps as above to trying to understand what's going on. `Bitwise operator: ~` is a common way to replace the ugly `0/-1` comparison when using `indexOf` method. A double negation using `!!` will gives us a Boolean to tell whether it's found or not found

Answer (score 0):

`!!~` means bitwise not `~` followed by double negation `!!`.

**Bitwise not** operates by reversing all the bits in the operand.