# Filter array with multiple array

Tags: javascript, angular

I know this has been asked before but I can't seem to find the answer, how to filter multiple data array with valuearray ..?

```js
var array =[
    {
        id : '123',
        nama : 'name one'
    },
    {
        id : '456',
        nama : 'name one'
    },
    {
        id : '789',
        nama : 'name one'
    },
    {
        id : '012',
        nama : 'name one'
    }
]

var valuearray = [123, 456]

array.filter(r => valuearray.includes(r.id)))
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: `array.filter(i => ~valuearray.indexOf(Number(i.id)))`

Comment: `array.filter(r => valuearray.includes(Number(r.id)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `id` value in `array` is string type and values in `valuearray` is numeric type so you need to use `filter()` in addition of `parseInt()` for `id` values.

```js
var array =[
    {
        id : '123',
        nama : 'name one'
    },
    {
        id : '456',
        nama : 'name one'
    },
    {
        id : '789',
        nama : 'name one'
    },
    {
        id : '012',
        nama : 'name one'
    }
]

var valuearray = [123, 456];
var res = array.filter(i => ~valuearray.indexOf(parseInt(i.id)));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you do it is like this

`array.filter(element => valuearray.includes(parseInt(element.id)))`

This will result, following the inputs you have given as example, in the following array:

`[{ id : '123', nama : 'name one' }, { id : '456', nama : 'name one' }]`

I see several answers here using the `~` operator. If you are wondering why that is, it is because `indexOf` could be `0`. If the result of the filtering function is `0`, the element will be filtered out, since it is a falsy value. The `~` prevents that.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299665/what-does-a-tilde-do-when-it-precedes-an-expression) should give you more information if you are interested in the `~`.

---

Edit:

As @str mentioned, `valuearray` has numbers while the `id` of elements in `array` are strings. This is why we use `parseInt` to ensure both terms of the comparison ( the `includes` function ) are of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that, in **array** each object id is string and in the **valuearray** each one is number.

so we need to convert the number with **[parseInt](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)** method and check.

```js
var array =[
    {
        id : '123',
        nama : 'name one'
    },
    {
        id : '456',
        nama : 'name one'
    },
    {
        id : '789',
        nama : 'name one'
    },
    {
        id : '012',
        nama : 'name one'
    }
]

var valuearray = [123, 456]


var filteredArray = array.filter(o => valuearray.includes(parseInt(o.id)))


console.log(filteredArray)
```