# What does the `~` symbol do in javascript?

Tags: javascript

What does the `~` symbol do in the `~j` and `~r`do?

```
sc=a=>[a.findIndex(r=>j=~r.indexOf('B')),~j];
```

It would be executed like this `sc(array)` where `a` is an array:

```
let a = [
  ["B", "A", "A", "A", "A"],
  ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A"],
  ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A"],
  ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A"],
  ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A"]
];
```

console.log(
  sc(array)
);

This is a solution to http://www.codewars.com/kata/shortest-code-bug-in-apple/javascript

Comment: I search and did not find any duplicates...

Comment: I searched and found the duplicate for you.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/28757111/362536

Comment: Thanks but how ~ is solving the test on codewar example? not getting how "sequence of 32 bits" is relevant at all here...

Comment: Read the specific answer I linked to, with its relevance to `indexOf`.